# How to remove part of a string, that's wrapped in <b></b>, with php?

Tags: php, string

So I have a text being pulled from db:

```
<b>Object title</b>
<br />
<p>Object description</p>
```

and I need to remove `<b>Object title</b>`, I tried using `substr`, but didn't quite come up with the correct way of putting it together. Can you please show me how I could do that?

**Edit**

Please note: I need to remove only the first `<b></b>` element, every other bold part of that string should stay the way it is.

Comment: Why don't you use `DOMDocument`

Comment: @Uchiha haven't used it, can you please provide an example? :)

Comment: I would do that with ereg_replace: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php (yes, it will require you read and find out how it's done).

Comment: For future reference: you're not removing the first "<b></b>" element (there is no such thing), but you are removing the first occurrence of texts "<b>" and "</b>" - those happen to be the opening and closing tags of an element if it were html, but when you pull text from a database, php doesn't know or care what we can make of it - it's just a text string. But this is just a side note ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u shoud use **preg_match** for this problem.

```
$text = "<b>Object title</b><br /><p>Object description</p>";

if (!preg_match("/<b>.*<\/b>/",$text,$m)) {
   str_replace($m[0],"",$text);
}
```

this should work for u.
if u want remove all u can run a a loop on $m.

Comment: Regex is not the correct tool to parse HTML/XML

Answer (score 0):

This can be obtained without the use of regex as well.
We are using simple PHP string functions here:

Try this:

```
<?php

function removeTags($subject, $replaceStr){
    $strlength = strlen($replaceStr);
    $subject = strstr($subject, $replaceStr, true) . substr(strstr($subject, $replaceStr), 0 + $strlength);
    return $subject;
}

$str = '<b>Object title</b><b>Object title</b><br /><p>Object description</p><b>Object title</b>';
$brOpenRemoved = removeTags($str, '<b>');
$brCloseRemoved = removeTags($brOpenRemoved, '</b>');
echo $brCloseRemoved; // final output
?>
```

The function removeTags removes the string provided to it. We have provided tags here.

It only removes first occurrence because we are using functions like `strstr()` which only work on first occurence of the string.

**EDIT**

We can use below function to prevent calling the same function again and again

```
<?php

function removeFirstOccurence($subject, $replaceTag){
    $replaceStrings = ['<'.$replaceTag.'>', '</'.$replaceTag.'>'];
    foreach($replaceStrings as $replaceStr){
        $strlength = strlen($replaceStr);
        $subject = strstr($subject, $replaceStr, true) . substr(strstr($subject, $replaceStr), 0 + $strlength);
    }
    return $subject;
}

$str = '<b>Object title</b><b>Object title</b><br /><p>Object description</p><b>Object title</b>';
$brRemoved = removeFirstOccurence($str, 'b');
echo $brRemoved; // final output
?>
```

Comment: I think I like the first function better - its more versatile.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there is your pattern in the text:

```
//remove first <b> tag
$text = '<b>foo</b>...';
$pos = strpos($text,'<b>');
if ($pos !== false) {
    $newtext = substr_replace($text,'',$pos,strlen('<b>'));
}

//remove first </b> tag
$pos = strpos($text,'</b>');
if ($pos !== false) {
    $newtext = substr_replace($newtext,'',$pos,strlen('</b>'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$limit` to the maximum possible replacements for each pattern in `preg_replace`

```
$yourString = 
"<b>Object title</b>
 <br />
 <p>Object description</p>";

$limit = 1;
$pattern = "/<b>(.*)<\/b>/";
$replace = "";

$newString = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $yourString, $limit);
echo $newString;
```

output:

```
<br />
<p>Object description</p>
```

If you use `(.*)` you can also delete `<b>` and `</b>` tags and just stay with the content:

```
$limit = 1;
$pattern = "/<b>(.*)<\/b>/";
$replace = "$1";

$newString = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $yourString, $limit);

echo $newString;
```

output:

```
Object title
<br />
<p>Object description</p>
```

Or keep only tags without content:

```
$limit = 1;
$pattern = "/<b>(.*)<\/b>/";
$replace = "<b></b>";

$newString = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $yourString, $limit);

echo $newString;
```

output:

```
<b></b>
<br />
<p>Object description</p>
```